# How do I disable login of user?

Tags: ubuntu

I made a user once with the `--disabled-login` command. I then had to change the password so I could login to the user and test some stuff. I do now want to disable the login again, and I saw this post:
[what does `adduser --disabled-login` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96892/what-does-adduser-disabled-login-do)

So I used `sudo passwd user` and then set it to `!`. However, when I tried to login I could login using the password `!`. So how do I disable it again?

Note that I also tried `*` as password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that your confusion stems from the fact you don't understand what `!` does.

Encrypted passwords are stored in `/etc/shadow`. For example, after
creating a new user named `new-user` and giving it `12345678` password
we get this entry:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow
(...)
new-user:$6$zVbJcpZE$Bqnxr5cDkwjKOE06iAZu7/qIuH9UGXex28TU/aD0osft9DfdPVzcVwq2j410YxoPlZR310.heZyxaQq4iwWy9.:18038:0:99999:7:::
```

You can now switch to `new-user` by doing `su new-user` and typing
`12345678` as the password.  You can disable a password for
`new-user` by prepending it with `!` like that:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow
(...)
new-user:!$6$zVbJcpZE$Bqnxr5cDkwjKOE06iAZu7/qIuH9UGXex28TU/aD0osft9DfdPVzcVwq2j410YxoPlZR310.heZyxaQq4iwWy9.:18038:0:99999:7:::
```

From now on you will not be able to switch to `new-user` even after
providing the correct password:

```
$ su new-user
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

Notice though that modifying `/etc/shadow` manually is very dangerous
and not recommended.  You can achieve the same with `sudo passwd -l new-user`.  As `man passwd` says:

> ```
>    -l, --lock
>        Lock the password of the named account. This option
>        disables a password by changing it to a value which matches
>        no possible encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning
>        of the password).
> ```

For example:

```
$ sudo passwd -l new-user
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

However, notice that `passwd -l` does not disable the *account*, it
only disables *password* and that means that user can still log in the
system using other methods as `man passwd` explains:

> ```
>        Note that this does not disable the account. The user may
>        still be able to login using another authentication token
>        (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators
>        should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's
>        expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
>        Users with a locked password are not allowed to change
>        their password.
> ```

Comment: The problem when I lock the account is that services that uses that account are no longer working?

Comment: You didn't really *locked* the account, you just disabled logging with password for this account. What is more, this is a normal security practice on Linux and other Unix-based systems to have multiple accounts with password disabled and shells set to `/bin/false` so that each daemon can be run on the behalf of different user. How exactly do you check that services that uses that account you've just modified are no longer working?

Comment: I can no longer connect to any of the services used by the user. If I use `passwd -u user` again, the services works after reboot. I solved this by `sudo adduser --disabled-login test-user` and then manually editing /etc/shadow and copy paste w/e was after `test-user` and put it after the user I wanted to disable. That is I just removed the hash after `!`

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are the services you're talking about no longer running, that is you cannot see them in output of `ps aux`?

Comment: Future investigation showed that it is just 1 service that do not work this way and where I have to manually remove the hash after `!` in `shadow`. Not sure why this specific service do not work but I have a solution that do work so thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misunderstood what's going on when there is a `*` or `!` as the "password value" in `/etc/shadow`. You can't achieve this by actually changing your password to a single-character `*` or `!`. Such single-character values are the result of locking the user account with commands such as `usermod -L`.

If you want to know more, please read : [Exclamation marks and asterisks in the password field](http://doc.callmematthi.eu/Linux_systemFiles.html#_etc_shadow__exclamationMarkAsteriskInPasswordField).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `usermod --lock`.

Comment: Now all the services that used the account are no longer running.